# Keyboard accessible React component that mounts on hover and focus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, onblur, onfocus

In a React application, I have a grid of `<Card />` components. Each `<Card />` renders several `<Button />` components.

Due to constraints outside my control, `Button` is an inefficient component. It is expensive to render, and we need to render hundreds of `<Card />` components, so it becomes a performance concern.

To account for this, **I only want `<Button />` to mount/render when the user is actively interacting with the `<Card />`**:

- When the user hovers on `<Card />`, mount `<Button />`
- When the user keyboard-navigates into `<Card />`, mount and focus `<Button />`.
- Allow keyboard users to fully cycle forwards/backwards between `<Card />` components

The hover portion is fairly straightforward, and my implementation can be seen below.

I am having trouble with the keyboard portion. Since `<Button />` is not mounted yet, how can the user keyboard navigate to it?

[CodeSandbox link of what I've tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-tdd-ou93x?file=/src/App.tsx)

This *mostly* works, except in two important ways:

1. the first `<Button />` should receive focus as soon as the `<Card/>` is tabbed into (not requiring a second tab press)
2. reverse keyboard navigation (ie shift+tab) does not allow any `<Button>` to be focused. It should focus the "last" button, and allow the user to navigate through all the buttons and then out to the previous `<Card>`

**Question: What modifications must I make to the below code to support the above two points?**

```js
import { useState, Fragment, useEffect, useRef, MutableRefObject } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function Card() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showButtons, setShowButtons] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const containerRef: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null> = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowButtons(isHovered);
  }, [isHovered]);

  return (
    <div
      onMouseOver={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      onFocus={(event) => {
        event.persist();
        setIsHovered(true);
      }}
      onBlur={(event) => {
        event.persist();

        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          if (containerRef.current) {
            setIsHovered(
              containerRef.current.contains(document.activeElement) === true
            );
          }
        });
      }}
      tabIndex={0}
    >
      <div ref={containerRef}>
        <h2>Card</h2>
        {showButtons && (
          <Fragment>
            <Button>Expensive Button One</Button>
            <Button>Expensive Button Two</Button>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is it that makes these buttons so computationally expensive? As rendering the buttons should take next to zero computational effort could you not render them as part of the card but use a very simple event listener on them that links to whatever is computationally expensive only on click (have a very light weight handler that then mounts the logic (which I am assuming is what is causing these buttons to be heavy) only when the button is first clicked). The current way of attempting to do this is fraught with problems as screen reader users do not navigate with <kbd>Tab</kbd> generally.

Comment: For example I can navigate via a buttons list - which would be next to impossible with the dynamic mounting and unmounting, I could jump to headings which would also be really difficult (or impossible) to detect as it won't trigger a focus event etc. Having the buttons in the DOM is almost essential and any workarounds we do would be very complex to account for different navigation methods. So I am suggesting we look at moving the complexity (however we are able given the fact you said we can't change the buttons much) elsewhere and have the buttons visible.

Comment: Could you perhaps mount all buttons that are visible on the screen (or only render the visible cards) and then lazy load the rest? I cannot imagine rendering 15-20 cards at a time could be too taxing. Then if performance suffers once a user scrolls remove the buttons when they are a certain distance off-screen again. Bear in mind you would have to ensure space is assigned for the buttons so there are no layout shifts. I hope the comments are clear, but any questions to clarify (or reasons we can't do one of the above options) let me know. **The key here is the buttons need to be rendered.**

Comment: Using `<button>` or not shouldn't impact performances so much, even if you have 100 of them. Your problem is probably elsewhere, and you should first try to fix this problem before inventing workarounds that are going to be difficult to maintain and make well accessible. The simplest is often the most accessible as well, KISS principle.

Comment: @QuentinC this is not using the native HTML `<button>`. this is a custom `<Button />` component. I'm using an HTML button for sake of example. This is unfortunately a hard restriction so "change the button" is not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the desired outcome with simple CSS (the `opacity` property) and a state change on focus.

Be aware that making a non-interactive Card container component interactive with `tabIndex={0}` is an anti-pattern.

```
//styles.css
.invisible-button {
opacity:0;
}


//Button.tsx
import React, { useState, FC } from "react";
export const Button: FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({
  children,
    }) => {
  const [hasBeenFocused, setHasBeenFocused] = useState(false);
  const handleFocus = () => setHasBeenFocused(true);
  const handleBlur = () => setHasBeenFocused(false);
  return (
    <button
      className={hasBeenFocused ? "" : "invisible-button"}
      onFocus={handleFocus}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      onMouseEnter={handleFocus}
      onMouseLeave={handleBlur}        
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
export default Button;
```

Have a look at the complete sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/intelligent-matsumoto-frc9kk?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A14%2C1

If you wish to have just the buttons receive focus you do not need to make your card component interactive with the tabIndex property.

I hope my solution helps :-)

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the asker's scenario— they need to avoid rendering the button entirely unless the user hovers the container.  Rendering but hiding it does not meet this need, no?  Unless I'm misunderstanding your answer, or the question?

Comment: making a non interactive Card interactive is an anti-pattern. If the Card is not supposed to be interactive but only the buttons inside are, then simply tabbing throught the page will make the buttons appear as the receive focus.
Buttons are interactive elements and are expected to receive focus.
With the example code above the requirements of the asker are met in my opinion :-)
My example above can be expended to have `onMouseEnter` make the buttons appear on hover too